# erro Column cannot be nul ao usar multpart/form-data

Tags: php, html

se eu usar o multpart/form-data na tag FORM eu consigo salvar o arquivo porem nao salva o nome do arquivo no banco de dados mas se eu tirar o multipart/form-data nao envia o arquivo mas salva no banco, como posso arrumar isso?

```
<input type="file" class="form-control mr-3 my-3" name="arquivo1" id="imageSlideInput1" placeholder="Imagem do Slide" />
```

```
<?php
    require '../conexao_banco.php';
// verifica se foi enviado um arquivo 
if(isset($_FILES["arquivo1"]) && $_FILES["arquivo1"]["error"] == 0)
{



    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES["arquivo1"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome = $_FILES["arquivo1"]["name"];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $novoNome;  

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {


        }}
}


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO conte_site_1 (cont_nav_1, titulo_slide_1, texto_slide_1, titulo_slide_2, texto_slide_2, titulo_slide_3, texto_slide_3, titulo_acima_slide, titulo_menu_suspenso_1, texto_menu_suspenso_1, titulo_menu_suspenso_2, texto_menu_suspenso_2, titulo_menu_suspenso_3, texto_menu_suspenso_3, id_usuario, arquivo1) VALUES (:cont_nav_1, :titulo_slide_1, :texto_slide_1, :titulo_slide_2, :texto_slide_2, :titulo_slide_3, :texto_slide_3, :titulo_acima_slide, :titulo_menu_suspenso_1, :texto_menu_suspenso_1, :titulo_menu_suspenso_2, :texto_menu_suspenso_2, :titulo_menu_suspenso_3, :texto_menu_suspenso_3, :id_usuario, :arquivo1) ");


        $stmt->bindParam(':cont_nav_1', $_POST['cont_nav_1']);


        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_slide_1', $_POST['titulo_slide_1']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':texto_slide_1', $_POST['texto_slide_1']);

        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_slide_2', $_POST['titulo_slide_2']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':texto_slide_2', $_POST['texto_slide_2']);

        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_slide_3', $_POST['titulo_slide_3']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':texto_slide_3', $_POST['texto_slide_3']);

        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_acima_slide', $_POST['titulo_acima_slide']);

        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_menu_suspenso_1', $_POST['titulo_menu_suspenso_1']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':texto_menu_suspenso_1', $_POST['texto_menu_suspenso_1']);

        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_menu_suspenso_2', $_POST['titulo_menu_suspenso_2']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':texto_menu_suspenso_2', $_POST['texto_menu_suspenso_2']);

        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_menu_suspenso_3', $_POST['titulo_menu_suspenso_3']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':texto_menu_suspenso_3', $_POST['texto_menu_suspenso_3']);

        $stmt->bindParam(':id_usuario', $_POST['id_usuario']);

        $stmt->bindParam(":arquivo1", $_POST["arquivo1"]);


        $stmt->execute();


        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Site Criado Com Sucesso,"); self.location.href="pag_user.php";</script>'; 

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Ops... Erro no servidor: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: o que vc quer arrumar? não entendi bem

Comment: bom quando eu uso o multipart/form-data eu consigo enviar a imagem para a pasta porem nao grava a informacao no banco ``` $stmt->bindParam(":arquivo1", $_POST["arquivo1"]); ``` e se eu tiro o multipart/form-data nao envia a imagem para a pasta mas grava a informacao , gostaria de como fazer para funcionar os dois

Comment: porque quando usa o multipart/form-data não é mais $_POST e sim $_FILES, no caso ficaria $_FILES["arquivo1"]["name"] ou $_FILES["arquivo1"]["tmp_name"] que é o arquivo temporário

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: bom agora da erro Column 'cont_nav_1' cannot be null

Comment: bom consegui enviar porem agora quando salva a informacao no banco, Salva array gostaria que salvasse o nome do arquivo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93123/discussion-between-nycolas-and-wees-smith).